# Which algorithm is used for the H2O AutoML metalearner

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

We know that `h2o.automl()` uses GBMs, Random Forest, DNNs, GLMs, and Extremely-Randomized Forest as base-learners, but what algorithm is used as the metalearner to combine base-learners?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two Stacked Ensembles in H2O AutoML (v3.16), both use a GLM (with a non-negative weight constraint).  Other than the non-negative constraint, all the other hyperparameters for the GLM are the standard H2O GLM defaults.

In future iterations, we will introduce additional ensembles that use different algorithms for the metalearner (e.g. GBM).

Comment: Very thanks for your reply. However, there is one problem that  I don't clear. I saw you said in another question " metalearner is trained on (usually) cross-validated predicted values generated by the base learners", why "usually"? If my study object is time series data, could I divide my data into 3 parts:training, validation, and testing and use predictions of validation to train meta-learner? not cross-validation.

Comment: Yes, the time when you would not want to use cross-validated predictions is when you have time-series data.  If you have IID data, then CV preds will give the best results (which is why its most used) but you can also use a hold-out set to create the predictions which are used to train the metalearner if you want to save computation time.

Comment: but, I wonder that does this approach still meet the theoretical requirements of super-learning(stacking)  and ensure our results performs essentially as well as or better than any of the candidate learners?

Comment: The theoretical results of Super Learner rely on cross-validation, but you can still get an ensemble that's better than the best base learner using the hold-out method, it just won't be as good as the Super Learner.  If you are concerned about computation time, then a decent compromise is to use Super Learner with 2-fold CV (but if you have time-series, then you should still use the hold-out approach).

Comment: This approach is called Blending?

Comment: Yes "blending" is probably the most common name for this technique (the ensemble technique of using a hold-out set instead of cross-validated predictions).

Comment: how the AutoML process decide which is the next model to train? Is it used a Random Grid Search or some other kink of algos (I think that the meta-learner has a huge impact in this stage of the training)

Comment: @AndreaM We have a bespoke ordering for the algorithms (based on a number of optimizations) and the order is listed here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/automl.html#faq